# How to import other types into my TypeScript custom declarations file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, typescript-typings, enzyme

I have this TypeScript + React + Webpack + Jest + Enzyme fully working.

I feel the need to have some global function accessible in my test specs. I can do that by pointing the [`setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string) option in Jest configuration to a `.js` file and I have something like this:

```
const Enzyme = require("enzyme");
const React = require("react");

const getMuiTheme = require("material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme").default;

global.mountWithContext = (node) => {
    return Enzyme.mount(node, {
        context: {
            muiTheme: getMuiTheme()
        },
        childContextTypes: {
            muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
        }
    });
};
```

On my spec files I can call `mountWithContext()` and it will work just fine when I run the tests. But my editor does not recognize the function.

To work around that, I've created a `/typings/declarations.d.ts` file with this:

```
declare function mountWithContext(node: any): any;
```

Now my spec files recognize the `mountWithContext` function, but the types are "wrong". The correct definition would be more something like this:

```
declare function mountWithContext(node: React.ReactElement<any>): Enzyme.ReactWrapper<P, S>;
```

The `React.ReactElement` is correctly identified because the `@types/react/index.d.ts` file includes this:

```
export = React;
export as namespace React;
```

The same isn't true for Enzyme. There's no global `Enzyme` exported. Looking at `@types/enzyme/index.d.ts` there's something like this:

```
export interface ReactWrapper<P, S> extends CommonWrapper<P, S> {
    (...)
}
```

But even if I do this:

```
declare function mountWithContext(node: React.ReactElement<any>): ReactWrapper<P, S>;
```

It doesn't work. `ReactWrapper` is still not recognized.

I tried to import inside this `declarations.d.ts` file and that will allow me to use the type correctly, but my function declaration will stop being recognized in my spec files. I've also tried to add a triple-slash directive like this:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/enzyme/index.d.ts" />
```

And the file is recognized, but the `ReactWrapper` type still isn't.

**So... How can I have a TypeScript function declaration for my custom `mountWithContext` global function with all the proper types, like this:**

```
declare function mountWithContext(node: React.ReactElement<any>): ReactWrapper<P, S>;
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the TypeScript to pick up declarations for consumption in `.js` files or for consumption in `.ts` files?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Only `.ts` files.

Comment: Can you add your `tsconfig.json` file? There may be some type configuration issue. Also, for completeness sake could you try declaring a function like `cat() : ReactWrapper` in the globals file to confirm that the only problem is the declaration and not something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we would like to declare that the `global.mountWithContext` function exists and has the indicated type we can add the following to an empty declaration file in our project.

```
import React from 'react';
import enzyme from 'enzyme';

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      mountWithContext<P, S>(node: React.ReactElement<any>): enzyme.ReactWrapper<P, S>;
    }
  }
}
```

**Details**

Here is a break down each of the constructs in the above:

1. The `declare global` block: The purpose of this construct is to modify, to augment if you will, the global scope, either by introducing new declarations or by modifying existing ones, from ***within*** a non global context such as a module. Our declaration file is a module because it contains a top-level `import` clause that imports `ReactWrapper` from Enzyme. 
   Such a block is called a "Global Augmentation" and may appear in implementation files as well.
2. The `interface Global` wrapped in the `namespace NodeJS` structuring: In our tests we are accessing the `mountWithContext` function as a member of the global variable, incidentally named `global`, that is provided by the Node environment. This variable is already declared by the type declarations for Node at the same level as other environmental globals such as `process`. However, we need to augment its *type*, by adding a new member. The *type* of this global `global` is the `interface` `Global` already declared inside the `namespace` `NodeJS`, by the official declarations for Node. We accomplish this by declaring a new member of the  `interface` `Global`. Our augmentation needs to be wrapped in the `namespace` containing `Global` or else it would be considered a separate `interface`. Roughly speaking, lexical scoping applies. (recall that TypeScript interfaces can be declared multiple times in the same scope and that these declarations will be merged)

**Notes**

Where do we place this declaration?
Anywhere that will cause TypeScript to pick it up and include it in our compilation context.
By convention we will place it in a file named **globals.d.ts** in the root directory of our project. (Technically it can be named something else and go in a lower directory).

It is important to note that this declaration file is part of our application code and should be checked into source control.
It must ***not*** be placed alongside third party declarations in directories such as **typings**, **node_modules/@types**, or **jspm_packages/npm/@types**.

It is also important to note that this augmentation affects TypeScript files (`.ts`, `.tsx`, `.d.ts`) only. If we were rather declaring this function to be picked up by the TypeScript language service simply to provide intellisense when working in `.js` or `.jsx,` files, this approach will not work.

Comment: Doesn't quite work. Once I add an `import` statement to the `globals.d.ts` file, things like `import { KeyCodes } from "constants/events/KeyCodes";` on my app code stop working with `Cannot find module "constants/events/KeyCodes".`.

Comment: On a second test... The above didn't work because I was using a `typings/globals.d.ts` file. If I put that in a `app/globals.d.ts`, it works. But I'm not very fond of this. I though the `typings` folder was for declarations and now I have to mix declarations with my app source code. :(

Comment: Your impression of the purpose of this `typings` folder is not correct. It is for third party declarations installed with a package manager, typings or tsd, and generally not checked into source control. It is common for an app to have custom declarations and they should never go in that folder.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Just one other small question if you don't mind, do we really need the `declare global { namespace NodeJS { interface Global {`? Is the `global`, `NodeJS` and `Global` random picked or do they special meaning?

Comment: No problem, I'll add the additional information to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Aluan :) I'm still having some conflicts though... I had a `globals.d.ts` file before (inside the `typings` folder, but I just moved to the `app` folder) and added you're code above to that file. But I'm still having some import issues. For the record, I have this on that file: http://pastebin.com/dMdu8e3U

Comment: The `declare module '*';` is allowing me to import CSS and image files (that are loaded with Webpack loaders) and it also allows me to import some TypeScript modules like `root/path/Module` instead of `../../root/path/Module`. I'll have to look into this more carefully and understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You do not need to modify anything in the `typings` directory to use this solution. Anyway the `globals.d.ts` file in that folder has a different purpose, namely to introduce certain declarations installed by the "typings" package manager into the global scope. Also note that I used the name `globals.d.ts` only by convention. You could call it `augmentations.d.ts`, `mount-with-context.d.ts`, or anything else. With respect to wildcard module declarations, I would suggest `declare module "*.css";` over `"*"` as the latter will match anything not otherwise resolved, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature is wrong, you have to declare the generic types first, for example:

```
function foo(T: bar): T // wrong
function foo<T>(T: bar): T // right
function foo<T extends K, K>(T: bar): K // right
```

In your case something like this should work:

```
declare function mountWithContext<P, S>(node: React.ReactElement<any>): ReactWrapper<P, S>;
```

If you happened to know what `P` and `S` are about you can be more specific, using `<P extends React.Component, K>`, for example.

Comment: That can't be it... I still get a `Cannot find name 'ReactWrapper'.`.

Comment: @tiagohngl is correct about the declaration of type arguments.